# How to copy file from remoter server (which is on another domain) to local?

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a file from remoter server(which is on another domain) to local

I am new to powershell and got this code from tech forum, however its not working

```
$Source = "\\xx.xxx.xxx.xx\Users\test\test_1.txt"
$Dest   = "D:\Demo\"
$Username = "domainname\username"
$Password = "xxx"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)

$WebClient.DownloadFile($Source, $Dest)
```

getting below error

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:9 char:1
+ $WebClient.DownloadFile($Source, $Dest)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Comment: Try to map the server as a drive with `New-PSDrive` and use the credential parameter. After that you can copy files with `copy-item`

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadFile` is expecting a [URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) as the first parameter, not a UNC path. Have you tried prepending `file:`? Like this `$Source = "file:\\xx.xxx.xxx.xx\Users\test\test_1.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your problem is you need to specify the full file path. Not just a target folder. Looking at [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.8) we can see

> `fileName` **String**
>
> The name of the local file that is to receive the data.

So perhaps all you need to do is...

```
$Source = "\\xx.xxx.xxx.xx\Users\test\test_1.txt"
$Dest   = [io.path]::Combine("D:\Demo\", Split-Path $source -Leaf)
```

It was probably denied access to write to a folder.